# How to increase Java heap space on Spark Amazon EC2 cluster?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, heap-memory

I wrote a program using Java Spark API. Given my data is big, I am getting the following error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Any idea how to increase java heap space of Spark EC2 cluster on Aws? I can give details about my code and cluster setup if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the error log for the problem? It will help others to get a better overview of the problem.

Comment: `Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
at org.apache.spark.network.Message$.create(Message.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.network.ReceivingConnection$Inbox.org$apache$spark$network$ReceivingConnection$Inbox$$createNewMessage$1(Connection.scala:438)
....10 more lines ....
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to increase the Heap space by adding two flags while submitting the application jar to spark-submit .

> --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 2g